# Get position of iterator error

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, distance

I have some code like this

```
forAllIter(PtrDictionary<phaseModel>, fluid.phases(), iter)
{

PtrDictionary<phaseModel>& PtrDict = fluid.phases();
int IteratorPosition = std::distance(PtrDict.begin(), iter);

}
```

where 'forAllIter' is a macro with the general structure

```
#define forAllIter(Container,container,iter)                                   \
  441     for                                                                        \
  442     (                                                                          \
  443         Container::iterator iter = (container).begin();                        \
  444         iter != (container).end();                                             \
  445         ++iter                                                                 \
  446     )
```

Unfortunately, when compiling my code I get the error

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘distance(Foam::DLListBase::const_iterator, Foam::LPtrList<Foam::DLListBase, Foam::phaseModel>::iterator&)’
```

I guess the problem is that the iterators are of different types? Has someone a solution or an idea to fix this problem?

Edit: Code of Class PtrDictionary :

```
namespace Foam
   48 {
   49 
   50 /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*\
   51                         Class PtrDictionary Declaration
   52 \*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
   53 
   54 template<class T>
   55 class PtrDictionary
   56 :
   57     public DictionaryBase<DLPtrList<T>, T>
   58 {
   59 
   60 public:
   61 
   62     // Constructors
   63 
   64         //- Construct given initial table size
   65         PtrDictionary(const label size = 128);
   66 
   67         //- Copy construct
   68         PtrDictionary(const PtrDictionary&);
   69 
   70         //- Construct from Istream using given Istream constructor class
   71         template<class INew>
   72         PtrDictionary(Istream&, const INew&);
   73 
   74         //- Construct from Istream
   75         PtrDictionary(Istream&);
   76 };
   77 
   78 
   79 // * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //
   80 
   81 } // End namespace Foam
   82 
   83 // * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //
   84 
   85 #ifdef NoRepository
   86 #   include "PtrDictionary.C"
   87 #endif
   88 
   89 // * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //
   90 
   91 #endif
```

Edit2:

method begin():

```
template<class T>
  363 inline typename Foam::PtrList<T>::iterator Foam::PtrList<T>::begin()
  364 {
  365     return ptrs_.begin();
  366 }
```

iterator constructor (hope this is the right one):

```
 iterator(LListBase_iterator baseIter)
  192             :
  193                 LList<LListBase, T*>::iterator(baseIter)
  194             {}
```

greetings streight

Comment: can we have some code from `PtrDictionary` class ?

Comment: @Raxvan Code of class added.

Comment: use a regular for loop instead of the macro?

Comment: @ Graham Griffiths: When you look at the definition of the macro `forAllIter` `iter` should be of type `PtrDictionary<phaseModel>`. However, when you look at the error message it seems `iter` is of type  `Foam::LPtrList<Foam::DLListBase, Foam::phaseModel>::iterator&`

Comment: @Streight cam we have a look at the `begin` function and the iterator constructors ?

Comment: what is the return type of fluid.phases() ? If it is not the same as PtrDictionary<phaseModel> then that will be the root of the problem

Comment: @GrahamGriffiths: The return type of fluid.phases() is PtrDictionary<phaseModel> - that s not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restating without the obfuscating macro, it seems that

```
PtrDictionary<phaseModel>::iterator
```

has type

```
Foam::DLListBase::const_iterator
```

whereas

```
fluid.phases().begin()
```

returns something of type

```
Foam::LPtrList<Foam::DLListBase, Foam::phaseModel>::iterator&
```

so somewhere the type is changing...either when assigning the container from fluid.phases(), or when returning the iterator from begin()

Comment: I ll check on this :)

Comment: I have used a different way of solving the problem, but I guess the direction you ve pointed would have leaded also to a solution and I would have tried it if the library I am working with was described completely